# Detect silence using Prosody Speech API

Tags: java, audio, jna

I am using Aculab's Prosody audio card that records sounds from a certain channel. I now want to trigger an alert if the channel is "silent" for e.g. 24h. Anyone has any experience on how to implement this using the Prosody Speech Processing API? I am implementing this in Java, using JNA for native calls.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with the Java part of it, but I'm assuming the Aculab API is roughly the same for everyone, so:

There are two options for this.  If you are recording the channel alaready and are using the Aculab high-level recording API, then there is a paramamter for "max silence" which will cause the recording to stop if the channel is silent for this long.  I've never used it for periods more than a few seconds myself though:

http://www.aculab.com/support/pdf_documents/v6_linux/TiNG/pubdoc/gen/apifn-sm_record_start.html#field-max_silence

As you can see in on that web page, this requires the Prosody firmware module "grunt", which can be used more directly using sm_listen_for.  You are likely to already use this if you are listeing for DTMF, and you'll see that this function also has a paramamter for "gruint detection", see here:

http://www.aculab.com/support/pdf_documents/v6_linux/TiNG/pubdoc/gen/apifn-sm_listen_for.html

If grunt detection is enabled, a detection (much like a DTMF detection) will be raised to say there was a sound.  I use this on my system to track which person in a conference is talknig at any given time, and it works quite well.  In your case, you just want to write code to see if there's no "grunt" (noise on the line) for a long time, so just track when you last got one of these signals.